# SpringCacheBasedUserCache is null

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cache

I have web applicatoin who use spring boot, spring security and spring data. it is stateless.

I would like to avoid to alway call db for user acess. So i thinking using SpringCacheBasedUserCache.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("city"), new ConcurrentMapCache("userCache")));
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserCache userCache() throws Exception {

        Cache cache = (Cache) cacheManager().getCache("userCache");
        return new SpringCacheBasedUserCache(cache);
    }
}


@EnableCaching
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return new UserServiceImpl(commerceReposiotry, repository, defaultConfigRepository);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have a class who implements UserDetails and another who implements UserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

    private final CommerceRepository commerceReposiotry;
    private final UserAppRepository repository;
    private final DefaultConfigRepository defaultConfigRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserCache userCache;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(final CommerceRepository commerceReposiotry, final UserAppRepository repository, final DefaultConfigRepository defaultConfigRepository) {
        this.commerceReposiotry = commerceReposiotry;
        this.repository = repository;
        this.defaultConfigRepository = defaultConfigRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserDetails user = userCache.getUserFromCache(username);
        UserApp userapp = null;

        if (user == null) {
            userapp = repository.findByUsername(username);
        }

        if (userapp == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + username + " not found");
        }

        userCache.putUserInCache(user);

        return new CustomUserDetails(userapp);
    }
    ...
}
```

In loadUserByUsername method, userCache is null

Comment: Your `UserServiceImpl` isn't a spring managed bean so nothing will be injected. Next to that your code is flawed. The `user` you put in the cache will always be `null`.

Comment: Instead of doing caching yourself, just wrap your own `UserDetailsService` in a `CachingUserDetailsService` which does the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either put `@Bean` on the `userDetailsServiceBean` method or (as suggested) remove caching from your `UserDetailsService` completely and wrap it in a `CachingUserDetailsService` and instead simply override the `userDetailsService` method instead.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserCache userCache;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {

        UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl(commerceReposiotry, repository, defaultConfigRepository);
        CachingUserDetailsService cachingUserService = new CachingUserDetailsService(userService);
        cachingUserService.setUserCache(this.userCache);
        return cachingUserService;
    }
    ...
}
```

You already have `@EnableCaching` on your other configuration so no need to have that again. Simply inject the cache into the configuration class and construct a `CachingUserDetailsService` which delegates to your `UserDetailsService` to retrieve the user.

Ofcourse you will have to remove the caching from your own `UserDetailsService` which can now be focused on user management/retrieval instead of being mixed with caching.

**Edit(1):** The constructor isn't public making it harder to create a bean. This can be achieved using `BeanUtils` and `ClassUtils`. Replace the call to `new` with the following should create an instance.

```
private UserDetailsService cachingUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService delegate) {
    Constructor<CachingUserDetailsService> ctor = ClassUtils.getConstructorIfAvailable(CachingUserDetailsService.class, UserDetailsService.class);
    return BeanUtils.instantiateClass(ctor, delegate);
}
```

**Edit (2):** Apparently I already encountered this once already (about 2 years ago) and registered [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2837) for it.

Comment: CachingUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService) is not public

Comment: Darn missed that the constructor wasn't `public`. Weird thing is with xml it is pretty easy to configure, but for java based configuration apparently it can only be configured (easily) for `jdbcAuthentication`. You could work around it by using the `BeanUtils` with the `ClassUtils` to create an instance. (See modified answer).

Comment: ok and if user modify its password, i need to removing user of the cache?

Comment: Then you either need to make your `UserDetailsService` managed by Spring (as mentioned by placing an `@Bean` annotation on the method) to get the cache and do the invalidation etc. yourself. Or you could make it event driven using spring `ApplicationListener` and publisher.\

Comment: @M.Deinum am I missing something when `ClassUtils.getConstructorIfAvailable()` doesn't find the constructor? I see there's a fix in 3.2.x to be released soon hopefully

Comment: 3.2 is old and unsupported, so expect no more releases from either Spring nor Spring Security for that version.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 5.2. I figured it out though, so no worries. Just didn't have enough caffeine in my bloodstream :)