# Caching UserDetails using Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cache

I am trying to implement a `UserCache` in my application to avoid to make multiple calls to the User table in the case I am using the basic authentication.  I created my `CacheConfig` following the accepted answer of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766098/springcachebasedusercache-is-null), in which the `CachingUserDetailsService` is used to manage the user cache. Bellow is the code of the `UserService`, `CacheConfig` and `SecurityConfig`:

```java
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository repository) {
        this.userRepository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {


        AddInUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("O usuário " + username + " não pode ser encontrado!"));

        UserDetails userDetails = User
                .builder()
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .roles("USER")
                .build();


        return userDetails;
    }

    @Transactional
    public AddInUser save(AddInUser user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }


}
```

```java
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    public static final String USER_CACHE = "userCache";

    /**
     * Define cache strategy
     *
     * @return CacheManager
     */
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        List<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<>();

        //Failure after 5 minutes of caching
        caches.add(new GuavaCache(CacheConfig.USER_CACHE,
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()));

        simpleCacheManager.setCaches(caches);

        return simpleCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserCache userCache() throws Exception {
        Cache cache = cacheManager().getCache("userCache");
        return new SpringCacheBasedUserCache(cache);
    }


}
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserCache userCache;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**")
                        .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserService userService = new UserService(userRepository);
        CachingUserDetailsService cachingUserService = new CachingUserDetailsService(userService);
        cachingUserService.setUserCache(this.userCache);
        return cachingUserService;
    }

}
```

The first call works well because it makes the call to the `UserRepository`. But on the second, it does not make the call to the repository (as expected) but I am getting the following WARN from `BCryptPasswordEncoder`:

```
2020-09-24 08:43:51.327  WARN 24624 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Empty encoded password
```

The warning is clear in its meaning and it fails to authenticate de user because of the `null` password. But I cannot understand why the user retried from cache has a null password if it was correctly stored. I am not sure how to solve it using the cache. Any thoughts?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That's not an error, it is a warning. Did you get your expected response?

Comment: @dur No. It fails to authenticate.

Comment: The problem is your `UserService`. You are loading your own user, which in turn is changed to a [`User`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html). Now as `User` also implements `CredentialsContainer` after authentication and before further reuse the password will be removed. As you are caching that object there will not be a password anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum is it possible to implement UserCache with redis because because i get deserialization error with SimpleGrantedAuthority ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@M.Deinum comment is absolutely correct. You can refer to the doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.0-RC1/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html).

> Note that this implementation is not immutable. It implements the
> CredentialsContainer interface, in order to allow the password to be
> erased after authentication. This may cause side-effects if you are
> storing instances in-memory and reusing them. If so, make sure you
> return a copy from your UserDetailsService each time it is invoked.

You can check the Spring-security [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6d14482378ff1fddd571966fb8dc3acdf7d11071/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.java#L102) if you are curious more:

```
private boolean eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication = true;
    
...

if (result != null) {
    if (this.eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication && (result instanceof CredentialsContainer)) {
        // Authentication is complete. Remove credentials and other secret data
        // from authentication
        ((CredentialsContainer) result).eraseCredentials();
    }
    // If the parent AuthenticationManager was attempted and successful then it
    // will publish an AuthenticationSuccessEvent
    // This check prevents a duplicate AuthenticationSuccessEvent if the parent
    // AuthenticationManager already published it
    if (parentResult == null) {
        this.eventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And [User.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6d14482378ff1fddd571966fb8dc3acdf7d11071/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java#L157) source code:

```
@Override
public void eraseCredentials() {
    this.password = null;
}
```

By the way, it looks weird to cache login user that way. During login, it is better to get fresh record from DB instead of from cache. You can use cached user at other place but seldom see it is used during login.

If you really need to do that, you can change the default flag to `false` as mentioned in [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html), just inject `AuthenticationManager` and call:

```
setEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication(false)
```